# django - how can I access the form field from inside a custom widget

Tags: django, django-forms

The below class inherits from the **Textarea** widget and features javascript code that displays how many characters more a user can enter in a textarea.

```
class TextAreaWithCharCounter(forms.Textarea):

    class Media:
        js = ('js/jquery.charcounter.js',)

    def render(self, name, value, attrs = None):
        id = attrs['id']
        max_length = self.attrs.get('max_length', 200)
        output = super(TextAreaWithCharCounter, self).render(name, value, attrs)
        output += mark_safe(u'''
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                        $("#%s").charCounter(%d, {classname:"charcounter"});
                        </script>'''%(id, max_length))        
        return output
```

The relevant portion of the form code is as follows:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    foo = forms.CharField(max_length = 200, widget = TextAreaWithCharCounter(attrs={'max_length':200}))
    ...
```

You can see that I pass the **`max_length`** argument twice, one for the field and one for the widget. A better way may be accessing the form field from inside the widget and get its max_length attribute, so that a max_length argument won't be required by the widget. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically, a Widget doesn't have to have a direct relationship back to a Field, so you don't do this.

Looking at the [source of `CharField`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2591fb8d4c0246f68b79554976c012039df75359/django/forms/fields.py#L184), you can see that it has a `widget_attrs` method which automatically adds the `maxlength` attribute to `TextInput` / `PasswordInput` fields.

I suggest you use a custom Field which overrides this method and adds an attribute for your custom Widget.

Also, I'm not sure that leaving it in `attrs` is a good idea anyway - the `<TextArea>` will be rendered with an invalid `max_length` argument. Perhaps you should be `pop()`ing it off instead?

Answer (score 16):

Although not required for solving your problem, access to the form or form field may be indeed useful sometimes. See the full answer at [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671446/country-state-city-dropdown-menus-inside-the-django-admin-inline/2135647#2135647), but in short, you can bind the form or field to the widget manually in form `__init__`:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    foo = forms.ModelChoiceField(Foo.objects, widget=CustomWidget())

    class Meta:
        model = Bar

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['foo'].widget.form_instance = self
```

Comment: From inside the Form class you can access the Model instance through `self.instance`. Remember the instance will be rather blank when Add/Creating a new object.

Comment: In recent versions, you can access the instance via `value.instance` in  `render(self, name, value, attrs = None)`